# Merge two collections with Automapper by condition

Tags: c#, automapper

There are two types:

1) DTO type:

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class OrderDetailDto
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MergeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PostionName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

2) corresponding domain type:

```
public sealed class OrderDetail
{
    public Guid MergeId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostionName { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

and two collections: `Collection<OrderDetail>` and `Collection<OrderDetailDto>`.

`Collection<OrderDetailDto>` has data changes, that was made somewhere. Now I want to apply these changes to `Collection<OrderDetail>`, using Automapper.

For simplicity, let's think, that *items count* in these collections are equal, but the *order of items* may differ.

To map collection items correctly, I want to use `MergeId` property. I need something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Collection<OrderDetailDto>, Collection<OrderDetail>>()
  .MappingExpression((dto, do) => dto.MergeId == do.MergeId);
```

Is this possible to do with Automapper?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found better solution than using custom converter like below.

```
    public class Converter : ITypeConverter<Collection<OrderDetailDto>, Collection<OrderDetail>>
    {
        public Collection<OrderDetail> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var destCollection = (Collection<OrderDetail>) context.DestinationValue;
            var sourceCollection = (Collection<OrderDetailDto>)context.SourceValue;
            foreach (var source in sourceCollection)
            {
                var dest = destCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.MergeId == source.MergeId);
                Mapper.Map(source, dest);
            }
            return destCollection;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution could simply to combine a linq query + automapper.

the basic concept is show here :

```
   var res = from a in orderDetails
              join b in orderDetailsDto on a.MergeId equals b.MergeId
              where a.Update == true // determine update selector here
              select new { a, b };

    res.Each(item => Mapper.Map<OrderDetail, OrderDetailDto>(item.a, item.b));
```

It is also easy to extract a generic extension method (based on the join extension method) for all merges

Answer (score 0):

i have modified k0stya's answer in a genetic way

```
 public class ListToListConverter<TEntity,TDto> : ITypeConverter<Collection<TDto>, Collection<TEntity>>
    where TEntity : class
    where TDto:BaseDto
{
    public Collection<TEntity> Convert(Collection<TDto> dtos, Collection<TEntity> entities,ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var destCollection=new Collection<TEntity>();   
        foreach (var source in dtos)
        {
            var dest = entities.SingleOrDefault(d => ((dynamic)d).Id == source.Id);
            context.Mapper.Map(source, dest);
            destCollection.Add(dest);  
        }
        return destCollection;
    }
}
```